# Initializing and keeping track of a large c++ object and reusing it from inside Mathematica

Tags: c++, mathlink-or-wstp

I have a c++ library function that calculates a distance between two vectors given an underlying matrix.

```
int d(const vector<float>& v1, const vector<float>& v2, const vector<vector<int>>& m) {
\\lots of stuff I don't want to understand 
}
```

Now the matrix `m` can be quite big and expensive to create. It has the same value for many evaluations of `d`. It only depends on an integer `i` that is determined once in a while during runtime.

So I would like to pass `i` and initialize `m`. 
Can I somehow initialize `m` as a c++ vector of vectors by calling c++ from Mathematica passing `i` and then somehow keep a handle on this c++ structure that I can pass to `d(v1,v2,m)`?

Or do I have to store the matrix in Mathematica itself? My fear is that it will be much bigger than the c++ equivalent and in the long run the memory usage will be a factor.

I hope the question is clear. I read many pages of documentation, but I could not figure out how to create and keep data on the c++ side in between calls. Maybe [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92112/11163) is similar, but I don't understand the example actually. And it has no answer.

Comment: "_It has the same value for many evaluations_".  Couldn't you save space by implementing it in Mathematica with [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) and also setting [`$HistoryLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HistoryLength.html) to zero.

Comment: @Edmund Sadly the array is not sparse. However if I would take the plunge and look into the library, I probably could calculate the entries on the fly almost as fast as the lookup as it is just a Hamming distance...maybe one day, but first I want to see it run. Also, I know it but the `$HistoryLength` thing is always a good tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done without using any Mathematica features.  You can keep the matrix as a global variable on the C++ side.  You will have a function for initializing it, a function for destroying it, and a function for the distance calculation.  Then just call the initializer and cleanup function manually from Mathematica when you need to.

Note: Storing a large matrix as `std::vector< std::vector<...> >` in C++ is not a good idea if you need performance.  Write your own class instead which stores the matrix as a flat array and indexes into it as `i*n + j` or similar.

If you need very good performance, do not use MathLink.  Use LibraryLink instead.  With LibraryLink, you can use "constant passing" for tensors: you can pass a Mathematica matrix to C++ without making an in-memory copy of it (and have read-only access on the C++ side).  See "Memory management of MTensors" in the LibraryLink documentation.

Since version 10, LibraryLink also provides "managed library expressions" (see again the LibraryLink tutorial).  These make it possible to have C-side data structures which get destroyed automatically once Mathematica no longer holds references to them.  This *might* simplify the first type of solution I mentioned where you have an initializer function and a cleanup function for the matrix.  It will ensure that the cleanup function gets called automatically once there's no Mathematica side reference to the matrix.

[Also take a look at my package `LTemplate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96128/12) which makes it easier to write this sort of code with managed library expressions.

With LTemplate the solution would look something like this (sorry for not testing this, I must leave in minutes):

The template:

```
template = LClass["Distance",
              {LFun["setMatrix", {Integer}, "Void"],
               LFun["dist", {{Real, 1, "Constant"}, {Real, 1, "Constant"}}, Real]}
           ];
```

C++ code:

```c
class Distance {
    YourMatrixType m; // may even be an mma::RealMatrixRef, i.e. an MTensor
public:
    ~Distance() { /* must clean up m if already initialized */ }

    void setMatrix(mint i) { /* initialize m */ }

    double dist(mma::RealTensorRef v1, mma::RealTensorRef v2) const {
        // compute distance between v1 and v2 based on m
    }
};
```

Now in Mathematica:

```
CompileTemplate[template]
obj = Make["Distance"]
obj@"setMatrix"[i]
obj@"dist"[v1, v2]
```

When there's no more references held by Mathematica to `obj` (e.g. you do `obj =.` and it's not stored in `Out[...]` either) then the destructor will automatically be called and the matrix `m` is freed.

Comment: The `LTemplate` package is great! I had to rewrite the library a bit to deal with the `mma::RealTensorRef` data, but now it is running and I will be able to optimize it much further if I need to. Also from now on I will be able to quickly include C++ code whenever I want to and interface with it just like with mma after loading.

Comment: @tortortor Glad to hear that!  I did see your previous comment (that you deleted), just haven't had time to respond yet ...

Comment: @tortortor `mma::RealTensorRef` is just a thin wrapper for an `MTensor`.  It would be a good idea to get familiar with the plain C LibraryLink API first, as this C++ class just simplifies working with those ... An `MTensor` stores multidimensional data as a flat array, and uses row-major storage, meaning that `{{1,2},{3,4}}` and `{1,2,3,4}` are stored the same way (plus information on their dimension).  You can access this data directly.  If you want, you can make an `std::vector` from them.  `std::vector` has a constructor that takes a C array and a size, so no need to copy elements manually.